# How does $U(x,t;x',0) \to \delta(x-x')$ as $t \to 0$ preserve the norm?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, greens-functions, propagator

If the propagator approaches the dirac delta as the difference in time decreases then we would expect
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \langle \Psi(x,t) | \Psi(x',0) \rangle$$
$$\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} |\Psi(x',0|^2 \delta(x-x')^2 dx$$
But how is that ever equal to 1?

Comment: I don't think the dirac delta is an operator that transforms a wavefunction into another one.

Comment: See the third question on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral kernel of the evolution operator converges (in a strong sense, i.e. when applied to wavefunctions) to the integral kernel of the identity operator, that is the delta distribution, as the time interval approaches zero.

However, the action of operators described by integral kernels on wavefunctions is not the one the OP writes.

In particular
$$\langle \psi (0),\psi(t)\rangle=\langle \psi (0),U(t)\psi(0)\rangle=\int \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}x' \psi(x)U(t;x,x')\psi(x')$$

The limit $t\to 0$ of the scalar product can be taken because of the strong continuity property of evolution operators (in particular it can be roughly speaking exchanged with the integral), yielding
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\langle \psi (0),\psi(t)\rangle=\int \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}x' \psi(x)\delta(x-x')\psi(x')=\langle \psi(0),\psi(0)\rangle$$